# Verify email "from" address using AWS/SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, verification, aws-ses

I'm setting up an email service with AWS SES (Simple Email Service).

When SES receives an email sent to, e.g. `launch.nukes@my-domain.com`, it will perform some action.

To prevent anyone from triggering the action, I check the `from` address is a known user.

However, anyone could create their own email server and send emails using a fake `from` account.

Is there anyway that I can verify that the `from` address is actually a known user? If not, what work arounds might exist?

Note: the actual action taken will be to forward the received email to a list of many other people. It doesn't need super secure.

Comment: There are a variety of methods for doing this. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear Thanks for the feedback - I've done more research and posted some possible solutions as an answer. If you know of any others solutions, please post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, here are several approaches I've found

1. Send a reply email back to the email sender, with a link requesting to confirm the action.
2. Make the user [digitally sign the email](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/secure-messages-by-using-a-digital-signature-549ca2f1-a68f-4366-85fa-b3f4b5856fc6).
3. Check the domain/IP/MX records as per [this question](https://superuser.com/a/86623/954684).